# My Remote Desktop Connection knows the administrator password on my old computer that I forgot

Tags: passwords

My old computer is running XP Professional. I am running Windows 10 and I can access my old computer with my Remote Desktop Connection. I am the Administrator on the XP so I need the current password to change it. That is the password I forgot. Like I said my RDC has the password stored but I can't get it. I have tried looking for a fix but I can't find the RDC File. I made the hidden files visible but still can't find it. There are programs on my old computer that I use on occasion but I have to do it from my study upstairs. I have to go upstairs every time I want to use it. It's a hassle. Can anyone help me.

Comment: If you don't use EFS or similar, simply reset the password from the management console? There's literally a ton of ways to bypass password authentication once you have physical access. Windows 10 probably stores it in the credential store.

Comment: It's unlikely the password is stored in plaintext. it will be a hash.

Comment: with xp, its trivial to reset the admin password using offline tools if you can boot it off CD/USB. That seems like the best approach. alternately since you are able to login to the system via RDP, you can change your password online using Ctrl+Alt+End, and selecting Change Password.

Comment: @FrankThomas if OP must RDP into the server, then it's unlikely that he has physical access.